# direct connectivity between html5 and mysql

Tags: mysql, html

I am a newbie on HTML5. I know this is a silly question but I heard about the connectivity between mysql and html5 using php. but can we do direct connectivity between both without php? If yes, please guide me with your suggestions and the tutorials.

Comment: HTML doesn't connect to anything. You probably mean *Javascript*. And yes, theoretically it's possible, but you really shouldn't want to, since that means publicly exposing access to your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alone HTML wont let you connect to mysql DB. But yes, the server side javascript can help you to achieve what you are trying to do. There are node.js modules available to connect and query mysql DB. You have to install node.js and then you can write the backend in Javascript.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Well, you wouldn't be able to connect to it directly with html5, as it runs client-side. This means that the code for html5 (most likely some form of javascript) will run on the client, but your mysql system is on another server. Normally, you don't directly open up access to a database to the web (security reasons).

On the other hand, as other posters have mentioned, you can run javascript server-side. I'm not sure why you would want to do this, though, when php is probably a more powerful and better suited tool for this type of operation.

You can do it with php, though, as you mentioned. Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php